# Java performance on money representation and currency conversion?

Tags: java, double, real-time, currency, bigdecimal

I'm working on a real time application that has performance issues as BigDecimal is what has been used to store money amounts. For that reason, now we have money stored as cents, or actually the smallest amount in whatever currency we are working with.

We deal with different currencies and the question we need to answer really fast is "how much of B do we get with these units of A?". It's worth mentioning we can't round that amount up, i.e. we need what would be actually possible to convert, no more.

Using `double` to store the exchange rates is tricky. Sometimes the rate will be slightly higher (or lower) than the real decimal number, so the result may be off by 1 unit every now and then.

```
double rateJPYUSD = 10.0; // 10.0 JPY/USD

long multiplierUSD = 100; // USD cents
long multiplierJPY = 1; // JPY units

long amountUSD = 1230; // 12.30 USD
long amountJPY = (long) (amountUSD * rateJPYUSD / multiplierUSD * multiplierJPY);
```

Here `amountJPY` may be either 123 or 122 depending on whether the double number (10.0) is slightly above (10.0000000001) or below (9.9999999999) the actual decimal number (10).

So the question is what is the fastest way to get it right?

Comment: What about representing the exchange rates as rational numbers (with a `long` numerator and a `long` denominator)? Also, I think it would be very important to have a whole flock of good unit tests with the most problematic cases you've seen and/or can think of.

Comment: The rate is given as a json string in an api ("10.0"), I'm parsing it as a double. Converting it to a rational number could work, though it probably requires converting it to double (which would have the same problem) or BigDecimal (which is slow).

Comment: You could convert it to a rational just by checking the number of places the decimal point has to be moved right to make it a whole number (the number of places after the decimal point), and then dividing it by ten to that power. So "10.0" becomes "100" (parsed to a long or BigInteger) over 10**1 i.e. 10. "123.45" would become 12345 over 100, etc. No need for double or BigDecimal.